# Mercurial: how to recover from an interrupted "qpop -a"?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I've imported a couple of revisions into the queue and tried to pop them all. Unfortunately, according to some other Mercurial client accessing the same repository, `hg qpop -a` didn't complete successfully:

```
> hg qpop -a
popping 115.diff
popping 114.diff
popping 113.diff
popping 112.diff
popping 111.diff
abort: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
another process
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\library.zip\mercurial\dispatch.py:217:
DeprecationWarning: use lock.release instead of del lock
```

Now I'm not able anymore to push the patches back. Mercurial always complains about an "unknown node":

```
> hg qpush -a
mq status file refers to unknown node b6fb614866f1
abort: working directory revision is not qtip
```

What does this mean and how can this problem be resolved?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It sounds like your dirstate was corrupted by the failed operation.  A similar issue was reported to the `hg` mailing list a long time ago ([link](http://www.selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2008-October/022069.html)).  You should review this [blog post by Andreas Wuest](http://andreaswuest.blogspot.com/2009/11/what-to-do-when-your-mercurial-working.html) that goes over a recovery procedure.

It basically boils down to this:

```
$ > .hg/patches/status          # force mq to think no patches are applied
$ hg debugrebuildstate -r tip   # rebuild your working copy
```

This does not destroy your patch queue, nor does it lose any working copy changes that were not part of a patch.  However you need to carefully inspect (and maybe fix) file versions to get back to a clean working copy.

Comment: Thanks. I had read Andreas Wuest's article, but didn't understand the Unix command > .hg/patches/status :) I did now, thanks to your answer.

Comment: For anyone using multiple patch queues (hg qq), you'll have to clear the status file on whichever patch directory is corrupt, e.g., "> .hg/patches-default/status"